# IOS - programmatically pause / mute/ reduce volume of background music and then restore it

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need to temporarily mute/pause/reduce the volume of the background music on iPhone/iPod while my app plays a sound effect, and then restore it.

`MPMusicplayerController` methods work perfectly well for the iPod/iPhone Music app but not for 3rd party apps such as Spotify

Does anyone have an example of doing this using `AVAudioPlayer`, or something else? Changing the session category from ambient to playback, and then back again works reasonably well but introduces a brief but noticeable lag in my display

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this [article](http://what-when-how.com/ios-4/building-an-audio-playing-application-with-the-audio-toolbox-framework-ios-4/) helps you. Check out "AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord" category

Comment: Thanks Nazar. Will take a look. Seems like this isn't a very popular topic :)

Comment: the article mentioned is not helping to achieve "reduce sound of music played in 'Music' app while we play an audio in our application"